# Is it possible to drop a column from AWS Keyspaces table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cql, amazon-keyspaces

I need to write roll-in and roll-back scripts for AWS Keyspaces. Roll-in is

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (
  next_value_1 double,
  next_value_2 double,
);
```

What roll-back script should be? According to what's written at [Tutorial: Delete data in an Amazon Keyspaces table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/getting-started.dml.delete.html) I can't drop columns from a table.

> You can delete a column from a specific row, individual rows from a table, all the rows from a table, an entire table, or a keyspace.

Also there's no `ALTER TABLE xxx DROP ()` mentions in [DDL statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/cql.ddl.html#cql.ddl.table.alter) page.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you cannot.  From the [doc mentioned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/cql.ddl.html#cql.ddl.table.alter) in the original post, the supported syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name    

    [ ADD ( column_definition | column_definition_list)  ] 
    [[ADD | DROP] TAGS {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}]            
    [ WITH table_options [ , ... ] ] ;
```

It looks like you can `ADD` and `DROP` *tags*, but you can only `ADD` columns.  If you need to `DROP` a column, it looks like you'll have to recreate the table.

Despite how AWS Keyspaces is touted as a drop-in replacement for Cassandra, there are [many things that it simply does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/cassandra-apis.html).

Note that `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name` does indeed work in both [Apache Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html) and [DataStax Astra DB](https://astra.datastax.com).